# Is RestSharp.NetCore package free for commercial use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have developed an ASP.net core web API, which connects to a third party library.

That library is using oAuth 1.0  authentication, so I have used **RestSharp.NetCore** nuget package to create the rest client.

I just wanted to know if RestSharp.NetCore
is free or not?

Comment: Nuget packages are published with a specific license. Have you looked this up?

Comment: yes, there is no license details

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148146/open-source-code-with-no-license-can-i-fork-it) SwE question:

> if you cannot find any license information, then you cannot copy or modify it for any reason other than personal use.

Also, I'm not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice.